# Unable To join array elements and substitute with required entry but giving out TypeError: not enough arguments for format string Error

Tags: python, python-2.7

a. I have two arrays, one with %d's and %s's and the other array has the value to be substituted for them. 
b. I tried joining the array elements separately and wanted to print the final substituted values.

```
#!/usr/intel/bin/python2.7

import Tkinter
import Tkinter as tk

le_temp_list =  ['%s', '[%s-1:0]', '[%d:0]', '%s']
le_temp_list_val = ['reg', '`ADR_WTH', 31, 'green']
ar = `' '.join([str(i) for i in le_temp_list])`
ar_val = ','.join([str(i) for i in le_temp_list_val])

print ar
print ar_val
print ar % ar_val
```

Below is the output i get,

```
'%s [%s-1:0] [%d:0] %s'
reg,`ADR_WTH,31,green
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "padx.py", line 47, in <module>
    print ar % ar_val
TypeError: not enough arguments for format string
```

But I wanted the output as given below i.e. each of the %d and %s being substituted with the required values.

```
reg [`ADR_WTH-1:0] [31:0] green;
```

Later I wanted to do something like

```
val_array.append(ar%ar_val)
```

Comment: Right, Python expects 4 arguments: 2 strings, 1 number, 1 string, but gets only 1 (huge) string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `zip` to iterate through two lists in an interleaved fashion:

```
val_array = []

for x, y in zip(le_temp_list, le_temp_list_val):
    val_array.append(x % y)

print(' '.join(val_array))
# reg [`ADR_WTH-1:0] [31:0] green
```

Answer (score 0):

This works as follows:

```
"%s %d {N similar elements}" % (a, b, ...N similar values)
```

So, you should just do:

```
print ar % tuple(le_temp_list_val)
```

There's no need to create the string `ar_val` because it will be treated as the only argument.

Comment: But even for that it provides like,
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "padx.py", line 47, in <module>
    print ar % le_temp_list_val 
TypeError: not enough arguments for format string

Comment: @Vimo, yep, this works with tuples only, I missed that.

Comment: THanks for the clarification.